# Haskell - List comprehension accessing next element as well

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use list comprehension to return the list elements that differ from the next. So far I've got it working with patterns and guards but ultimately need to use list comprehension

So fn [4,3,3,1,1,3,3,3] and [4,3,1,3] would return [4,3,1]

This is what I've got so far which just returns an empty list

```
notEq'::[Int]->[Int]
notEq' il = [x | x <- il, fn il]
                where fn (a:b:xs) = a == b
```

Edit: Expanding more on the question, I want it to compare each element to the next and exclude the last comparison to []. So [4,3,3,1] would go something like this (4,3,OK), (3,3,NO), (3,1,OK) with the result [4,3]

Comment: It's not clear if you're saying that you _want_ it to exclude the last element, or that your current code does that and you want to fix that aspect.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've clarified it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're describing and the  example you gave seem to disagree.

The example output suggests that you're looking for a function that takes a list and returns a list of only the distinct elements. In that case, you're looking for [`nub`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-List.html#v%3Anub):

```
nub [4,3,3,1,1,3,3,3]
-- result is [4,3,1]
```

However, the function you describe in English and in your code takes a list and removes *adjacent* duplicates. In that case, you would expect the result for both example inputs to be `[4,3,1,3]`, not `[4,3,1]`. In that case, Haskell already has a function to [`group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) subsequences of adjacent, equal elements:

```
map head $ group [4,3,3,1,1,3,3,3]
-- result is [4,3,1,3]
```

If you *must* use a comprehension, maybe this will suffice:

```
[ x | x:xs <- group [4,3,3,1,1,3,3,3] ]
-- result is [4,3,1,3]
```

---

Now that you've clarified what you want to do, I think [`tails`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) would be your friend here:

```
let xs = [4,3,3,1,1,3,3,3] in
  [ a | a:b:_ <- tails xs, a /= b ]
-- result is [4,3,1]
```

I really don't understand why you want to exclude the last element. If you by chance wanted to include it, it would be easy to accommodate:

```
let xs@(x:_) = [4,3,3,1,1,3,3,3] in
  x : [ b | a:b:_ <- tails xs, a /= b ]
-- result is [4,3,1,3]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. And to expand more on the question, it compares each element to the next, and seems to exclude the last comparison to []. So [4,3,3,1] would go something like this (4,3,OK), (3,3,NO), (3,1,OK) with the result [4,3]

Answer (score 1):

Consider zipping each element of the list with its successor and filtering those pairs whose first and second item differ, like this,

```
notEq' :: [Int] -> [Int]
notEq' xs = map (fst) . filter (\(a,b) -> a /= b) $ zip xs (drop 1 xs)
```

For getting a list with labels, consider this,

```
pairing :: Eq t => (t, t) -> (t, t, [Char])
pairing (x,y) = (x,y,label)
  where
    label = if (x /= y) then "OK" else "NO"
```

and so

```
map (pairing) $ zip xs (drop 1 xs)
```

for `[4,3,3,1,1,3,3,3]` would deliver

```
[(4,3,"OK"),(3,3,"NO"),(3,1,"OK"),(1,1,"NO"),(1,3,"OK"),(3,3,"NO"),(3,3,"NO")]
```

**Update**

Using a comprehension, like this,

```
notEq' :: [Int] -> [Int]
notEq' xs = [ x | (x,y) <- zip xs (drop 1 xs), x /= y ]
```